# How to verify if user is an azure database subscriber account?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

In an on-premise SQL Server i can verify an sys-admin by this code:

```
SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin')
```

When using Azure SQL Database I have at least one [super user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins#unrestricted-administrative-accounts).
But how can I verify that I'm logged into SQL Database with this SUPER USER by not using it's name?

Regards,
Daniel

Comment: A 'super user'?

Answer (score 0):

According to the MSDN doc for [IS_SVROLEMEMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176015.aspx), it should be supported in a very similar way.

Now, your title suggests that you're asking something different than the text of the question. I'm addressing the text, feel free to edit if necessary.

Comment: So you're asking if you can tell if the user logged in is a server-level principal account?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, you can't. In Azure SQL Database, there's no server role concept. If you run below scripts, error occurs:
[image]

The database subscriber account is not assigned with any server role. Thus when you run `SELECT IS_SRVROLEMEMBER ('sysadmin')` it always returns 0.

Now let's see the database roles. I find the highlighted two database role names below are the same with my super user names(subscriber account and AAD admin account).

[image]

Then I look into the system view **[sys].[database_principals]** as below. From what I find here, it seems after the subscriber account and AAD admin account being created, two corresponding database roles are created but there's lack of officials docs about how it really works, I am just sharing what I found here with you, hope it helps.

[image]